# How to fix next.js error: Error: > Build failed because of webpack errors

Tags: next.js, netlify, deploying

I'm trying to deploy a next.js app to netlify and trying to get the output folder but when I run "npm run build" I get an error like: Error: > Build failed because of webpack errors
at build (C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\port_frontend\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js:15:918)

Comment: Can you provide any more info on the errors? Is there a build log perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install package again, you hvn't update the latest;

```
npm install
npm run build
```

OR

```
yarn install
yarn build
```

Answer (score 0):

For my case, delete `node_modules` folder, and run `yarn install` works for me

Answer (score -1):

change import next/App to lowercase ,it works for me