# Next.js build failing to compile ( HookWebpackError: <css input>:61:1: Missed semicolon)

Tags: css, typescript, webpack, next.js, css-modules

### The Problem:

next.js is failing to run the build command, even though I can run it in development mode with no problems. Its saying there is a missing semicolon in the css. Of course there isn't one, it wouldn't compile in dev mode if there was. And for general information, I am using css modules for this project. So all my css is name.module.css.

here is the warning the console gives, and it is the entire stack trace. Doesn't change if I run --debug flag either. and Im running `npm run build` which corresponds to the script `"build": "next build"` in my package.json.

```
> projectName@0.1.0 build
> next build

info  - Using webpack 5. Reason: no next.config.js https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5
info  - Checking validity of types  
info  - Creating an optimized production build  
Failed to compile.

HookWebpackError: <css input>:61:1: Missed semicolon


> Build error occurred
Error: > Build failed because of webpack errors
    at /Users/name/Documents/coding_files/personal_projects/projectName/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:17:924
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/Users/name/Documents/coding_files/personal_projects/projectName/node_modules/next/dist/telemetry/trace/trace.js:6:584)
```

### What I have tried:

First I looked up the issue here. I found a few posts with similar errors.

[Post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67644781/nextjs-build-errors-verbose-logging-shows-nothing) From post claification: this is my full stack trace shown.

[Post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64380840/how-to-fix-next-js-error-error-build-failed-because-of-webpack-errors) I ran `npm install` and it found nothing to update. and changed my import to `"next/app"` instead. Didn't help either.

Other than posts I did a dive into the next.js code in node_modules to try to understand what was happening and I got no where because its a webpack thing, which I did not realize. I also saw another post that I cannot find that said that this error happens with importing google fonts sometimes, so I commented out all my google fonts and this is still happening. I do not quite understand how it could give errors on build but not on dev.

### Closing thoughts

I suspect that something is being imported into some file somewhere, as that seemed to be the issue in the other post I read (the one I cannot find), however I cannot find it. That or my lack of next.config.js file is causing the issue ( I am a next.js beginner). Also, I am using typescript, if that helps.

Any help is really appreciated.

Thank you everyone

Comment: Without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it's hard to tell why you're getting the error.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is your NodeJS version?

Comment: Gotta love a nice, clear, and opaque error :D

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error. To address the issue I commented all the imports of components pulling their scss files into the component I suspected causing the issue. Then I started to uncomment components one by one and found the component causing the error. Then I commented out its scss file content and started to sequentially uncomment styles and finally found the line causing this.

In my case, this was the animation css property having the wrong order of params.